If $R := \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ is a ring with $D$ a negative integer, for what $D$ is this ring a ED, PID, UFD?
IS is understood that for say D = -1 this ring is a ED and so implies both PID and UFD. IF D=-3 then it is not a UFD and so a ED or PID. If D = -5 it can be show it is not a PID and so not a ED, I could still be a UFD I have not checked, what in general for what D is this ring either a ED, PID or UFD?

This has been answered here already! Have a look. Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

can you send me the link? please

@CarlGaussian The link to the tutorial and the duplicate have already been included...
